# Android - creating background image

Tags: android, image, resolution

I'm new to android programming and I was wondering about how to get a background image (`ImageView`) show a drawable with a correct size.

Let me explain well, let's imagine we have this image:

[image: background image]

I want this image to get shown with this aspect ratio on all screens.

Since I don't want the image to get stretched, I would like to set manually how my image gets shown, maybe by modifying its scale with thirdy part software.

the problem with this image is that, in portrait mode, it's not guaranteed to see the ball, and so I want to crop the part of my image so that the ball gets shown on the bottom-right edge.

I know that I have to import my drawable for all resolutions, but simply importing does not help... Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I'm facing this problem with dynamic background `ImageView`, so I'm not going to user `xml` layout files.

Using `scaleType` attribute doesn't help for this, or at least not just by setting its value.